# Vertically spread/spaced screen elements using Autolayout and Interface Builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode5, autolayout, uistoryboard

I have a relatively simple portrait-only UI, laid out in a Storyboard, with items which I want to vertically spread to fill both 3.5 inch and 4 inch screens.

In other words, I want the spacing between the controls to be adjusted so that the UI nicely fills the screen, irrespective of the screen form factor.

This doesn't seem like an unusual thing to want to do, however I just can't get Interface Builder (within Xcode 5) to add the right constraints - I only seem to be able to get it to add fixed vertical space constraints, which do not adjust for different screen sizes.

Does anyone know how to do this without resorting to programmatic UI construction?  I've invested a lot of effort in getting the Storyboard-based UI just right.

The solution needs to work on both iOS 6 and 7. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have more than 2 controls stacked vertically that you want to spread out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to do this depends on exactly what kind of adjustment you want when the screen size changes. One way to do it to give the top and bottom most views vertical spacing constraints to the top and bottom of the superview, respectively. Add a view, I usually use a UILabel with no text, in between all the views you have stacked vertically, and give them equal heights to one another. Give one of those "spacer" views a fixed height, but edit it so its priority is less than 1000 (which means it's not mandatory that it be satisfied). Then add spacing constraints between each nearest neighbor above and below each "real" view and the "spacers", so that you have all the views from top to bottom connected together by vertical spacing constraints. When the screen size changes, the only thing that can change will be the height of the "spacers", since the priority is less than 1000, and all other constraints are mandatory. My constraints look like this:

[image]

The labels each have the standard (8 point) spacing to the "real" views above and below them. The top and bottom views should have whatever spacing you want to the screen edges.

Comment: Setting the priority on the spacer views to less than 1000 was the missing piece of the jigsaw - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Apple have now posted a document which describes the officially-endorsed approach to solving this problem:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH5-SW8

Summary of the approach: insert spacer views between your controls, which have equal width/height (as applicable) constraints.